# org-roam and persp-mode.el: persp-def-auto-persp has nil (buffer-file-name)

Tags: hooks, org-roam, persp-mode

I would like all org-roam buffers to automatically go into a `persp-mode.el` perspective.

`org-roam-mode` is a global minor mode, so I can't use that as a way to detect whether a new buffer is for org-roam.

I tried this:

```
(defun my/roam-buffer (_buffer state)
  (let ((name (buffer-file-name)))
    (when (and name (s-contains-p "/org-roam/" name))
      (if (null state)
          't
        state))))

(with-eval-after-load 'org-roam
  (setq org-roam-db-location (expand-file-name "~/.org-roam.sqlite"))
  (persp-def-auto-persp "org-roam"
                        :parameters '((dont-save-to-file . t))
                        :predicate 'my/roam-buffer
                        :dyn-env '(after-switch-to-buffer-functions ;; prevent recursion
                                    (persp-add-buffer-on-find-file nil)
                                    persp-add-buffer-on-after-change-major-mode)
                        :hooks '(after-switch-to-buffer-functions)
                        :switch 'frame))
```

However, `(buffer-file-name)` in `my/roam-buffer` is `nil`.  I'm guessing that's because initially when the buffer is created (again I'm guessing persp is hooking into that), it's not linked to a file yet?

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though `org-roam` has a hook specifically for this: `org-roam-file-setup-hook`. It's not well documented, but from reading the code it looks like it's called whenever an `org-roam` file is opened.

From my testing, that means when it's done through the normal `find-file` means, from `org-roam-find-file`, and probably just about everything else that opens files. This includes creating new files.

Here's the code I used to test, which you can adjust for your needs:

```lisp
  (defun bjc/test-roam-hook ()
    (message "org roam buffer opened in %S for file %S"
             (current-buffer) (buffer-file-name)))

  (add-hook 'org-roam-file-setup-hook 'bjc/test-roam-hook)
```

Comment: Ah, I'd actually forgotten I'd even specified a hook in my persp config code!  I'm sure I copied that part...

Comment: Just switching my code to use that hook instead of after-switch-to-buffer-functions seems to have done the trick